# Java - merge two classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, merge

I have two similar classes. I would like to merge it into one. Objects of these classes are used in many different places. Is it possible to do it safely in Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse can't do that. you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two classes that are similar in some ways (but possibly not in others), you could create an Interface that describes the methods that are common to both of them. Then, you would have your two classes implement that Interface. Elsewhere in your application, you could reference the Interface as the formal parameters to your methods. Here's an example (see code below).

There is no automatic way to do this in an IDE-- you've got to take the time to design your object hierarchy (the relationships between your classes, and the API that your application will use to interact with them) manually.

```
public Interface Automobile{
    //define an interface that describes the methods common to your two classes

    public void drive();
}

//this is one of your two classes 
public class Sedan implements Automobile{
    public void drive(){
        //Sedan-specific implementation here
    }
}

//here's the other one. It's similar in that it has a drive method, but different
//in that it's implementation for drive() is different, and there might be 
//other stuff in this class that is different from Sedan. However, it still is-an
//Automoblie
public class RaceCar implements Automobile{
    public void drive(){
        //RaceCar-specific implementation here
    }
}

public class YourApplication{

    //some method that accepts either one of the two classes you 
    //described as being "similar"
    public void someMethod(Automobile automobile){
        //you could pass in either a Sedan or a RaceCar, and
        //the corresponding drive() method would get called
        automobile.drive(); 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Automobile car1 = new Sedan();
        Automobile car2 = new RaceCar();

        someMethod(car1);
        //call the same method, but with car2!
        someMethod(car2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can't do that automatically, You will have to go to one class, press control+a then control+c then go to the other class and press control+v.

Comment: Maybe my question is not precise. I know how to merge two files :) I want other classes to know about it.

Comment: @user2357858 Oh, then no, Eclipse can't do that you will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use Refactor->Extract Interface for each class to create two new interfaces and change the sources to use them instead of the classes.

Now create a new class implementing *both* these interfaces and remove the old classes.  This should only cause your factory methods for the interfaces to break.

Change your factory methods to return this new class and leave all the interface usages in place.